# Python Bokeh, labeling Donut's outer rings

Tags: python, bokeh

I have code that will generate me a donut graph, but now I want to label the outer rings of the donut. My code is shown below

```
from bokeh.charts import Donut, output_file, show, save
def show_donut():
    xyvalues = [[4,1], [5,0], [7,0], [6,0]]
    donut = Donut(xyvalues, ['Available in Shop', 'Sold in shop'])                    

    output_file('donut.html')
    save(donut, "results.html",None,"Bokeh plot")
```

I have tried using ["Available in Shop", "arg1", "arg2"] for each element in the Donut constructor, but that didn't work. Any idea how I would accomplish that?

If I use list as arguments for the labels, here's what I get

[image]

Comment: Why didn't it work? Did you get an error?

Comment: @Meter no, I will post a screenshot of what will happen if I try to use list arguments for labels.

Comment: Check this out - it looks like you need to use an ordered dict :http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/donut_chart.html